# Error using Spring CachingConnectionFactory with Websphere MQ on Websphere Application Server

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq

I am getting the error below when using spring CachingConnectionFactory to connect to Websphere MQ on WAS

```
org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: **Method setExceptionListener not permitted;** nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Method setExceptionListener not permitted
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:279) ~[spring-jms-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169) ~[spring-jms-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:496) ~[spring-jms-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:568) ~[spring-jms-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:559) ~[spring-jms-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
```

My configuration looks like -

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsConnectionFactory"
            jndi-name="jms/XXXCF" />

<bean id="cachedConnectionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
            <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="50" />
        </bean>

<bean id="jmsResponseTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedConnectionFactory" />
            <property name="defaultDestination" ref="XXXQueue" />
        </bean>
```

Does anyone know if I am missing any configuration on spring or WAS side? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same kind of problem. After debugging the spring code I found that ibm has trouble with this because of a setting "reconnectOnException"

By adding

> < property name="reconnectOnException" value="false" />

to your cachedConnectionFactory. you bypass this problem.

But now of course, after an exception was thrown, I get exceptions like this

- Producer closed
- org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: Session closed;
- javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Connection closed

Does anyone have an idea how to get IBM to play nice with the reconnectOnException="true" ?